Dynamic string array to Typescript type
I have a dynamic array that i want to build up from a json file, then supply that as a generic type with the list of the json data showing as options.
File Example. [{ PrivilegeKey: 'view.test'}, { PrivilegeKey: 'view.test1'}];
I then want to use this as a type;
type Privilege = MAGIC_CODE_HERE;
usage:
const test: Privilege = 'view.test|view.test1'
I had a look and everyone uses as "const", but this isn't working as per image.

i tried the above and it is not working

There has to be a good dupetarget for this.

TypeScript types don't exist at runtime (other than a small bit of enums). You can't create one using information that only exists at runtime.

I've seen other posts using static arrays and doing the same with as const, what makes a static json file any different

Does this answer your question? How to parse JSON string in Typescript

Because the JSON file isn't Typescript? It's completely opaque to the compiler. JSON.parse happens at runtime and Typescript only exists at compile time. JSON in a .json file is not the same thing as an array literal in the Typescript source code! JSON is a string until it is parsed.

@​user10589537 - You haven't said anywhere in your question that the file is static. (Also, what you've quoted isn't valid JSON, so I have to question whether it's really a JSON file. In JSON, property names must be in ".) If you really have a static JSON file, make it a TS file instead, add as const
and export as necessary, and you may be able to do something with it. But not if it comes into the program as a string (JSON). (Remember, if you're dealing with JS/TS code, and not dealing with a string, you're not dealing with JSON: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247.)

Screenshots of IDEs are unfortunately not appropriate here. Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions.  Then make sure that the plaintext is a [mre] we can all use to demonstrate the issue for ourselves, and we might be able to help in some way. But I agree with previous comments: JSON.parse() can't really be strongly typed the way you want. TS can possibly help you import a JSON file, but without a [mre] I don't have anything specific to recommend.

So the best way was as to only create a flat array in a ts file as Tj mentioned. This means i would need to manually extract the values i want every-time, but at-least it works for now.
Example
Example
Example

Screenshots of IDEs are still inappropriate for Stack Overflow. Unless you want the answer to attract as many downvotes as the question, you should [edit] to replace your images with plain text.
